# Combine multiple FluentValidation conditions with or?

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a property where I want to check if it is either empty or in a specific format. I know I could put both conditions in one regex, but using something like `Empty().Or.Matches(...)` would be far easier to read - is something like that possible using FluentValdations?

So current code:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property)
    .Matches(@"^$|^[0-9]+$"); // did not check the regex, but for this example it should not matter
```

I would prefer something like that for better readability:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property)
    .Empty().Or().Matches(@"^[0-9]+$");
```

Comment: Well, you can use `RuleFor(x => x.YourProperty).Must(BeEmptyOrMatchFormat)` with BeEmptyOrMatchFormat a boolean method returning `string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || Regex.IsMatch(value, @"your-regex-pattern")` you can also define multiple conditions based on different scenarios

Comment: nice idea, but I am looking for a more generic way, so I do not have to build own functions for every "or" combination (empty or matches was an example) - if that's possible using fluent validations. Otherwise I'd indeed go with that way.

Comment: Could you do something like this RuleFor(x => x.Property).Must(x => (x.Empty() || x.Matches(@"^[0-9]+$")); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the method's that are available now, it would have to by chaining or's `||` in the `Must` method.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\b(jack|jill)\\b");
RuleFor(validateField => validateField.Name)
  .Must(name => string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || regex.IsMatch(name))
  .WithMessage("Name must be empty or 'jack' or 'jill'");
```

[DotNet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gbdz6X)